# How do I use the REST API with a Jenkinsfile that points to a shared library?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Jenkins multibranch pipelines.

My jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
@Library('my-shared-library') _

// this pipeline lives in the shared library
mypipeline ([
    'some-param': "sldkjlkdjlsdjf",
    'some-param-two': "blbhablhablhab",
])
```

It calls a pipeline named `mypipeline` and passes it those params.

Is there a way I could call the Jenkins REST API and execute the jenkinsfile somehow? Like pass the `mypipeline` job this local jenkinsfile?

Comment: Hi there. I wonder if you could run your posts through a spell-checker - nearly all your posts are misspelled. Most browsers have a spell-checker pre-installed these days, and if the default is not set to English for you, it can usually be easily added.

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow is a curated Q&A site where questions and answers are written, improved, and kept, for the benefit of a wide future audience, and not merely for the immediate needs of the author.

Comment: not sure I understand your question. Do you mean to trigger the Jenkins job with the described Jenkinsfile on your question remotely? or from a different Jenkins Job?